# Homework C programming stack and heap with string

Tags: arrays, c, string, stack, heap-memory

This is a homework assignment that I could use some help with.  I seem to have everything working, but I am having issues with the the name of the games.  As you can see my names are not showing up appropriately in the output nor while I am trying to debug, its a lot of gibberish and such.  Could someone please explain what is causing this or give me an example on just one of the `games_stack[i].name[i]` to make it work appropriately?

[image: Output]

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000
#define PAUSE system("pause")

//Games Struct
typedef struct
{
    char name[50]; // name of game
    int mScore; // metacritic score
    char rating; // ESRB rating
}GAMES;

int main(void) {

    GAMES games_stack[MAX];

    int numElements = 10;

    int i;

    //Populate array in stack
    //games_stack[0].name[0] = "Bioshock Infinite";
    games_stack[0].name[0] = "Bioshock Infinite";
    games_stack[0].mScore = 94;
    games_stack[0].rating = 'M';

    games_stack[1].name[1] = "Half-life 2";
    games_stack[1].mScore = 96;
    games_stack[1].rating = 'M';

    games_stack[2].name[2] = "Mario Kart Double Dash";
    games_stack[2].mScore = 87;
    games_stack[2].rating = 'E';

    games_stack[3].name[3] = "Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess";
    games_stack[3].mScore = 96;
    games_stack[3].rating = 'T';

    games_stack[4].name[4] = "Rocket League";
    games_stack[4].mScore = 86;
    games_stack[4].rating = 'E';

    games_stack[5].name[5] = "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive";
    games_stack[5].mScore = 83;
    games_stack[5].rating = 'M';

    games_stack[6].name[6] = "Assassin's Creed II";
    games_stack[6].mScore = 80;
    games_stack[6].rating = 'M';

    games_stack[7].name[7] = "Batman: Arkham Asylum";
    games_stack[7].mScore = 91;
    games_stack[7].rating = 'T';

    games_stack[8].name[8] = "Middle-eart: Shadow of Mordor";
    games_stack[8].mScore = 84;
    games_stack[8].rating = 'M';

    games_stack[9].name[9] = "Portal";
    games_stack[9].mScore = 90;
    games_stack[9].rating = 'T';

    // Create an array on the heap to store the same number of populated elements from the stack array.

    GAMES *games_heap = (GAMES*)malloc(numElements * sizeof(GAMES));

    // if memory not allocated, exit

    if (games_heap == NULL)

    {

        printf("\n Memory not allocated");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    //Copy the values from the stack array into the dynamic array.

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)

    {

        games_heap[i].name[i] = games_stack[i].name[i];

        games_heap[i].mScore = games_stack[i].mScore;

        games_heap[i].rating = games_stack[i].rating;

    }

    // print the elements from both the array

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)

    {

        printf("\n Stack : ");

        printf(" Name: %c\t MetaScore: %d\t ESRB Rating: %c", games_stack[i].name[i], 
            games_stack[i].mScore, games_stack[i].rating);

        printf("\n Heap : ");

        printf(" Name: %c\t MetaScore: %d\t ESRB Rating: %c", games_heap[i].name[i],
            games_heap[i].mScore, games_heap[i].rating);

    }
    PAUSE;
    // write contents of heap to binary file

    FILE *filePtr = fopen("games.bin", "w");

    if (filePtr == NULL)

    {

        printf("Unable to open file");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)

    {

        if (i != numElements - 1)

            fprintf(filePtr, "%c %d %c\n", games_heap[i].name[i],
                games_heap[i].mScore, games_heap[i].rating);

        else

            fprintf(filePtr, "%c %d %c", games_heap[i].name[i],
                games_heap[i].mScore, games_heap[i].rating);

    }

    fclose(filePtr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

//end of program
```

Comment: `games_heap[i].name[i] = games_stack[i].name[i];` only copies one character. You probably want to lookup `strcpy`

Comment: %c prints a character. You want a string so use %s.

Comment: @John3136 Thank you both, stack is now printing the entire string. I also had to remove the [i] after .name. I am running into an issue with coping the values from stack to heap. What is the correct way to write this using strcpy? 'games_heap[i].name[i] = games_stack[i].name[i];' I tried to write it like 'strcpy(games_heap[i].name) = strcpy(games_stack[i].name);' but it says it must be a modifiable value.  I also tried to write it like //'strcpy(games_heap[i].name) == strcpy(games_stack[i].name)' but then niether stack or heap print correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- Your game name is a char array, so your game[i] is a character only. And you can not assign a string to a char. You better use strncpy.
- You can only assign the value to an array when you initialize it, so games_heap[i].name[i] = games_stack[i].name[i] doesn't work. Moreover, in this case, you only copy 1 character.
- Use %s to print a char array.

I add here a quick fix code to make it work basically. Sorry for not able to optimize it more since I am not an expert. Hope this help.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GAME_NAME_LENGTH 50
#define MAX 1000
#define PAUSE system("pause")

//Games Struct
typedef struct
{
    char name[GAME_NAME_LENGTH]; // name of game
    int mScore; // metacritic score
    char rating; // ESRB rating
}GAMES;

int main(void) {

    GAMES games_stack[MAX];

    int numElements = 10;

    int i;

    //Populate array in stack
    //games_stack[0].name[0] = "Bioshock Infinite";
    strncpy(games_stack[0].name, "Bioshock Infinite", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[0].mScore = 94;
    games_stack[0].rating = 'M';

    strncpy(games_stack[1].name, "Half-life 2", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[1].mScore = 96;
    games_stack[1].rating = 'M';

    strncpy(games_stack[2].name, "Mario Kart Double Dash", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[2].mScore = 87;
    games_stack[2].rating = 'E';

    strncpy(games_stack[3].name, "Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[3].mScore = 96;
    games_stack[3].rating = 'T';

    strncpy(games_stack[4].name, "Rocket League", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[4].mScore = 86;
    games_stack[4].rating = 'E';

    strncpy(games_stack[5].name, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[5].mScore = 83;
    games_stack[5].rating = 'M';

    strncpy(games_stack[6].name, "Assassin's Creed II", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[6].mScore = 80;
    games_stack[6].rating = 'M';

    strncpy(games_stack[7].name, "Batman: Arkham Asylum", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[7].mScore = 91;
    games_stack[7].rating = 'T';

    strncpy(games_stack[8].name, "Middle-eart: Shadow of Mordor", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[8].mScore = 84;
    games_stack[8].rating = 'M';

    strncpy(games_stack[9].name, "Portal", GAME_NAME_LENGTH);
    games_stack[9].mScore = 90;
    games_stack[9].rating = 'T';

    // Create an array on the heap to store the same number of populated elements from the stack array.

    GAMES *games_heap = (GAMES*)malloc(numElements * sizeof(GAMES));

    // if memory not allocated, exit

    if (games_heap == NULL)

    {

        printf("\n Memory not allocated");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    //Copy the values from the stack array into the dynamic array.

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)

    {

        strncpy(games_heap[i].name, games_stack[i].name, GAME_NAME_LENGTH);

        games_heap[i].mScore = games_stack[i].mScore;

        games_heap[i].rating = games_stack[i].rating;

    }

    // print the elements from both the array

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)

    {

        printf("\n Stack : ");

        printf(" Name: %s\t MetaScore: %d\t ESRB Rating: %c", games_stack[i].name, 
            games_stack[i].mScore, games_stack[i].rating);

        printf("\n Heap : ");

        printf(" Name: %s\t MetaScore: %d\t ESRB Rating: %c", games_heap[i].name,
            games_heap[i].mScore, games_heap[i].rating);

    }
    PAUSE;
    // write contents of heap to binary file

    FILE *filePtr = fopen("games.bin", "w");

    if (filePtr == NULL)

    {

        printf("Unable to open file");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)

    {

        if (i != numElements - 1)

            fprintf(filePtr, "%s %d %c\n", games_heap[i].name,
                games_heap[i].mScore, games_heap[i].rating);

        else

            fprintf(filePtr, "%s %d %c", games_heap[i].name,
                games_heap[i].mScore, games_heap[i].rating);

    }

    fclose(filePtr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

//end of program
```

Comment: thank you Nguyen Cong.This works fantastic. Out of curiosity and for learning I see you also added #define game_name_length and also used it after strcpy. What exactly does that do. I know it makes the length a max of 50, but isn't that what name[50] does in the struct? Again thank you, it works beautifully.

Comment: It is the same as you define MAX 1000, by doing this if you change the length of the game name, you don't have to change it in every line of code. You only have to modify the define statement.